# Importing external jars and Gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I see that many other users have encountered the error `Gradle: error: package <...> does not exist`, but I've tried following the various suggestions but to no avail. So any help will be much appreciated.

My project imports the Conceal jar as an external library, so it does not sit inside `libs`.

Here's my tree:

```
⇒  tree -L 3
.
├── MyApplication.iml
├── app
│   ├── app.iml
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   ├── intermediates
│   │   ├── outputs
│   │   └── tmp
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── libs.zip
│   ├── proguard-rules.pro
│   └── src
│       ├── androidTest
│       └── main
├── build
│   └── intermediates
│       └── dex-cache
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── local.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

My app/build.gradle looks like below

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.1'
}
```

I already have `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` under `dependencies`, so that should have the jar imported - correct? Or does the jar (or all of the jars for that matter) have to sit inside `libs`? If so, could I not import external jars?

Here's build.gradle under root

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I wonder if I'm missing something very obvious. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where do you import it? i cant find it listed as a dependency in either of the two gradle files. You can either add it to libs, or list it as a dependency within the gradle buildfile

Comment: Sorry, I left it out in my paste. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understand of this: https://github.com/facebook/conceal/issues/27
you need to reference it by using

```
compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.1@aar'
```

until this issue is fixed.

Comment: You're completely correct! Do you know what that suffix is supposed to do?

Comment: Im not entirely sure, but i guess that some sort of "index" file is missing atm, so you have to reference it, with the proper extension. But this is a guess, so i cant be sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the jar  into the libs folder
2. Right click it and hit 'Add as library'

Comment: Is it not possible to keep the jar external though?